# Plot scale cumulant generating function

Tags: python, simulation

I have a random walker which, at the ith step after resetting takes a jump drawn from a Gaussian distribution with zero mean and time-dependent variance (1-B/i), where B is a constance. Now I want plot scale cumulant generating function for this process using Python code.

This is my code. But it's not plot anything.

```
      import numpy as np
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    

     def stochastic_process(n_steps, reset_prob):
         B = 5
         x = np.zeros(n_steps) # inisiall aray of zeros
         for i in range(1, n_steps):
         var = max(0, 1 - B/i)  #time-dependent variance with minimum value 0
         if np.random.rand()< reset_prob:
             x[i] = x[i-1]
         else:
             x[i] = x[i-1] + np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = np.sqrt(var))
         return x

      # Calculate scale cumulant generating function
     def scgf( k ):
         GF = np.zeros(k)
         for k in range(0, k):
               GF = np.mean(np.exp(k*stochastic_process(n_step, reset_prob)) #calculate generating function
          return np.real(np.log(GF))


    plt.plot(scgf(2))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.